# How to read metadata from a given URL and save it as a json file with key_value pairs?

Tags: python, json, flask, rest

I have defined a URL in my python codes and I need to read it and save it in a json file then save them in a list or dictionary. In my codes I read and print them. Also, I would like to know is there any issue in my codes such as post method or read key value pairs from the URL?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests, json
import urllib.request as request

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

data = "given_URL" 
myjsondata = {}

@app.route('/my_folder/', methods=["POST"])
@app.error

class read(Resource):
    
    def read_data(self):
        with request.urllib.urlopen(metadata) as response:
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                source = response.read()
                data = json.loads(source)
                for i in data:
                    for key, value in i.iteritems():
                        if key == 'uid':
                            print key, value
                            myjsondata[key]=value

                return jsonify(myjsondata)

            else:
                abort(make_response(jsonify(404, massage = "No request found"),400))
            
api.add_resource(read, '/my_folder')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: your first "for loop" will never execute because "for i in data:}" is inside "if response.getcode() == 200:" code block and your "if response.getcode() == 200:" exits at "return jsonify(data)" before executing your "for i in data:"

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response. I just editted the codes accordingly and hope it is true.

Comment: seems you edited but its still wont execute, "return" or "abort" will exit without executing your for loop. Try placing "return data" after for loop...   same indentation space as "for i in data: "

Comment: Yes that's true. I just edited again. I'm not sure if I put the return in a right place or not.

Comment: this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the metadata.
Arrange keys and values in your way to make dictionary.

```
#Save extracted content to dictionary/list
myjsondata={}
for i in data:
    for key, value in i.iteritems():
        if key == 'uid':
           print key, value
           myjsondata[key]=value

#Save your dictionary content to json file
with open('saved_json_file_1.json', 'w') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(json.dumps())
```